# Shortcut to move between lines accessing a variable in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a shortcut to jump between the lines that access/read/write/use a variable? I notice that next to the scrollbar is a control that you can click on, but I have not found a shortcut to perform the same action yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> on that variable to find the references to that variable in a given class.

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> should work. But the problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> is, it is basically a search for the next occurrence of the highlighted text but not the exact variable.

Ex: you have a producer variable and createProducer() method, you highlight producer and start doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>(for reverse search) if navigates to both producer and `createProducer()` and other references to the string producer in the class.

I am not sure of the exact key board shortcut that you are looking for but this works and I am curious too to see if there is any other shortcut.

Comment: so Ctrl-Shift-U starts a search and then you navigate using Ctrl-. and Ctrl-,?

Comment: right and you can also use Up and Down arrows once you do a Ctrl+Shift+U